# Has Sherlock Holmes ever solved a case with Sci-Fi elements?

Tags: movie, books, novel

In the many novels and short stories that Arthur Conan Doyle wrote Sherlock Holmes and Dr Watson have solved a variety of cases including supernatural elements to politics but has Sherlock Holmes ever solved a case which had elements of sci-fi?
Note here I am only talking about the movies, books or series set in the late Victorian era and the Edwardian era when the original Sherlock novels are supposedly set (the series Sherlock and Elementary take place in the present day hence they don't count.)

Comment: The Hound of the Baskervilles was considered to be a supernatural demonic hound until the mystery was solved.

Comment: Yes but The Hound Of the Baskervilles was partly supernatural, and I am asking for a story completely sci-fi like including aliens time travel etc.

Comment: Per the [FAQ]; "*Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here: Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the books that have X?*  (In this case, all the books with Sherlock Holmes in a sci-fi setting)

Comment: There are at least 2 anthologies of such stories: *Sherlock Holmes through Time and Space* and *The Improbable Adventures of Sherlock Holmes*

Comment: If it were constrained to Doyle's works, or even ones that were released in his lifetime as collaborations or fanfic, I could see this as being more viable, but indeed, too open-ended for the site.

Comment: @Shanu  "A scandal in Bohemia" may indicate that SH is in an alternate universe with a different history.  The "Swamp Adder" in "The Speckled Band" may be an unknown species.  The Valley of Fear may be in an alternate universe to "The Final Problem" & "The Empty House".   Many chronological problems indicate that stories might be in alternate universes to other stories, and/or that there might be some unmentioned time travel, and/or that SH is in an alternate universe where the Victorians kept changing the calendar era and thus the number of the current year.  Sherlock Holmes may be SF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [*Sherlock Holmes's War of the Worlds*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38135) by Manly W. Wellman and Wade Wellman (1975)

In this story it is assumes that the Martian Invasion did occur rioughly as recounted by Wells, and the Holmes is a key figure in responding to it.

As a Holmes fan, I found it quite enjoyable.

It is really a fixup than a novel, ISFDB lists it as a collection.

It starts with the related Wells story "The Crystal Egg" told from Sherlock's PoV. The Egg allows Holmes to gain some advance intelligence of the Martian invasion. It seems Holmes was the mysterious person who bought the Egg at the end of the Wells story.

We the see many of the event4es of the invasion from Sherlock' PoV, and also from the PoV of George Edward Challenger, another Doyle hero.

It has been years since I read it, and I don't recall all the plot. I do recall that the unnamed "artilleryman" who Wells's narrator met and dismissed as a futile dreamer turns out to be a character from one of the Holmes stories, but I can't recall which -- 'll have to reread. I think I still have my copy.

I believe that Holmes was involved with ensuring the final end of the Martians.

---

The ISFDB has  number of stories tagged "Sherlock Holmes" but many of them probably do not fit the parameters of this question.

---

One short story not so tagged, but that does fit is  ["The Adventure of the Extraterrestrial"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41682) by  Mack Reynolds. In this an aged Holmes is living with an equally aged Watson. Holmes gets a client who is convinced that there are extraterrestrials present on earth. Watson is convinced Holmes has become senile. Holmes investigates, and

> finds that there are, in fact aliens among us, in part to look for alien criminals hiding here. He hires on, his initial fee being regeneration to a physically young body. Watson is left  startled.

Comment: so does it show war of the worlds from sherlock's perspective?

Comment: and can you please further elaborate the plot a bit

Comment: @shanu I have added some, and hope to add more after rereading

Comment: More than one novel freely stole from Wells' WOTW -- there was one in which Edison reverse engineers the Martian tech and Mars is invaded.

Answer (score 0):

The 2009 [Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_(2009_film)) film should count, in my opinion.

There are events that at first seem to be supernatural. Holmes investigates and discovers that there is a scientific explanation behind all of them.

But here's an interesting point. The science was a few years in advance of the period it was set. Moriarty's henchmen had invented radio several years before Marconi. In my opinion, science beyond the reality for the period makes it Science Fiction, YMMV.

A similar one is [The Private Life of Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Private_Life_of_Sherlock_Holmes), in which Holmes investigates the Loch Ness Monster, which actually turns out to be an experimental military submarine.

Comment: Doc Savage had the same idea: supernatural causes eventually shown to have natural explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the [2010 Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_(2010_film)) film in which a giant octopus and dinosaur appeared. The dinosaur is a small Tyrannosaurus that is first seen terrorising Whitechapel and is known as the "Monster of Whitechapel". The creature is revealed to be artificial when Sherlock Holmes discovers that its skin is made from rubber.

Comment: Tough to keep track of Asylum films, some/many of which were just terrible but I watched Black Summer episodes recently and it was superior to what one might have expected.